# Sockets failing to connect from Chromebook Linux terminal

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I'm running the most recent version of ChromeOS and I have had the following problem for about a month. Sockets over ssl (?) generally are failing to connect from the Linux (Beta) terminal environment. Specifically, `requests.get(...)` and `urllib3.http.request('GET',...)` are failing to reach `https://cern.ch`. The latter does reach `http://httpbin.org/robots.txt`, but not the former. `ping` fails in both cases. Several third-party API libraries fail to connect, and specifically time out reaching their host. `wget` reaches `http://httpbin.org/robots.txt` but not `https://cern.ch`. Any ideas about what I can do to get it fully working?